# Javascript Sort Object of Days in abbreviated form

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object of weekdays. How can i sort it in the correct order of Days of the week using javascript.

im also using date-fns in the app.

```
const INIT_SLOTS = {
  WED: [{startHour: ''}],
  SUN: [{startHour: ''}],
  MON: [{startHour: ''}],
  TUE: [{startHour: ''}],
  SAT: [{startHour: ''}],
  THU: [{startHour: ''}],
  FRI: [{startHour: ''}]
};
```

Comment: Object properties have a defined order that's only partially under your control. Relying on that is a fantastic recipe for bugs. If you need a specific order, create an array of  property names and sort it however you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modifying [@NinaScholz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) solution

```
const INIT_SLOTS = {
  WED: [{ startHour: "" }],
  SUN: [{ startHour: "" }],
  MON: [{ startHour: "" }],
  TUE: [{ startHour: "" }],
  SAT: [{ startHour: "" }],
  THU: [{ startHour: "" }],
  FRI: [{ startHour: "" }]
};
const sortByWeek = (slots) => {
  const DAYS = { SUN: 1, MON: 2, TUE: 3, WED: 4, THU: 5, FRI: 6, SAT: 7 };

  const KEYS = Object.keys(slots);

  const sortedKeys = KEYS.sort((a, b) => DAYS[a] - DAYS[b]);
  const ordered = {};
  sortedKeys.forEach(function(day) {
    ordered[day] = slots[day];
  });
  return ordered;
};

sortByWeek(INIT_SLOTS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with the days and values in wanted order and sort the array of keys by using the order of the days.

```js
const
    DAYS = { SUN: 1, MON: 2, TUE: 3, WED: 4, THU: 5, FRI: 6, SAT: 7 },
    INIT_SLOTS = { WED: [{ startHour: '' }], SUN: [{ startHour: '' }], MON: [{ startHour: '' }], TUE: [{ startHour: '' }], SAT: [{ startHour: '' }], THU: [{ startHour: '' }], FRI: [{ startHour: '' }] },
    KEYS = Object.keys(INIT_SLOTS);
    
KEYS.sort((a, b) => DAYS[a] - DAYS[b]);

console.log(KEYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, without hardcoding you can build the week days strings from JS `Date` as sorted order. (sun - sat) and then access items from your object. Check the following code, the result you will get array of items sorted asc from weekday begin to end.

```js
const getWeekdayStrings = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const dayms = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  const firstDay = new Date(today.getTime() - today.getDay() * dayms);

  const weekdays = new Array(7).fill(0).map((_, i) =>
    new Date(firstDay.getTime() + i * dayms)
      .toDateString()
      .split(" ")[0]
      .toUpperCase()
  );
  return weekdays;
};

const INIT_SLOTS = {
  WED: [{ startHour: "" }],
  SUN: [{ startHour: "" }],
  MON: [{ startHour: "" }],
  TUE: [{ startHour: "" }],
  SAT: [{ startHour: "" }],
  THU: [{ startHour: "" }],
  FRI: [{ startHour: "" }]
};

const sorted_slots = getWeekdayStrings().map(day => INIT_SLOTS[day]);

console.log(sorted_slots);
console.log(getWeekdayStrings());
```